# Careers 2.0 link mistake

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, hyperlinks

On the [about listings](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/about-listings) page on Careers, there's a list of sites the listings will run on. The last link is labeled `joelonsoftware.com`, but it actually links to `stackoverflow.com`:

[image: Screenshot of the page]

Comment: Ahh, I understand your question now. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops...I've checked in a fix that will go out later today.  Thanks for the report.